# PHP function 'scandir' shows deleted directory when deleted directory was open in Windows Explorer

Tags: php

I am running Apache HTTP server 2.4 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with PHP 5.4.4.

I have the following directory structure on my `E:\` drive:

```
E:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3
```

All of the directories (`Dir1`, `Dir2` and `Dir3`) are empty (they have no files) except for the child directories shown above.

I am trying to delete `Dir3` and then look at the contents of directory `Dir2` to make sure that there's nothing there.  I have written the following PHP script to test this:

```
<?php

    $currentDir = "E:\\Dir1\\Dir2\\Dir3";

    $parentDir = dirname( $currentDir );  // Get the parent directory for Dir3.
        
    rmdir ( $currentDir );  // Remove directory Dir3.
    
    echo "<b>Current directory:</b> " . $currentDir . " <b><< I don't exist, I was just deleted.</b><br />";
    echo "<b>Parent directory:</b> " . $parentDir. "<br />";
                
    echo "<b>According to 'scandir', the parent directory contains:</b> ";
    print_r( scandir( $parentDir, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE ) );
    echo "<br /><br />";

?>
```

If I do **not** have `Dir3` open in Windows Explorer, the script above woks perfectly and delivers the following output:

> **Current directory:** E:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3 **<< I don't exist, I was just deleted.**
>
> **Parent directory:** E:\Dir1\Dir2
>
> **According to 'scandir', the parent directory contains:** Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. )

However, if I have `Dir3` open in Windows Explorer, I get the following output:

> **Current directory:** E:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3 **<< I don't exist, I was just deleted.**
>
> **Parent directory:** E:\Dir1\Dir2
>
> **According to 'scandir', the parent directory contents:** Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => Dir3 )

Notice that `Dir3` appears in the array of contents for `Dir2`.  In other words, `scandir()` thinks that `Dir3` still exists even when I know for a fact that it doesn't (Windows explorer kicks me back to `Dir2`).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: Mine does not think so ..... difficult to replicate but try `clearstatcache();` before another `scandir`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the suggestion...I put a `clearstatcache()` after `rmdir()` and before `scandir()` and I get the same output...it says that `Dir3` still exists even though it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have the directory opened in windows explorer. There is an existing `handle` to the `directory` in the `OS-es memory`. `Scandir` internally fetches details of directory/file existence from the OS. So when the directory is open and you delete it and run a `scandir` immediately, then windows returns it because there is a `"lock"` on the directory handle. This handle closes only when you close the directory (or some internal garbage collections happens at the OS level I guess). When the directory is not open in windows explorer none of these edge cases are happening and so everything works like a charm.

Again one of the behaviors of windows. I think `clearstatcache()` is an option, but I believe it works only on `posix-compliant` Os-es and also `scandir()` is not affected by it.

Comment: Thanks for your response...it makes complete sense to me.